# How to add a custom program to WIndows 10 right-click context menu and pass highlighted text to it?

Tags: python, windows, contextmenu, right-click

So I would like to create a simple word counter program with Python and add it to the Windows 10 context menu which opens when you right-click something. My goal is to then be able to highlight some text somewhere (a webpage, Microsoft Word, etc.) and pass that highlighted text to the Python program as input. Is this possible...?

I have already figured out how to add a program to the context menu, as explained by this link: https://www.howtogeek.com/107965/how-to-add-any-application-shortcut-to-windows-explorers-context-menu/

I am stuck on figuring out how to pass the highlighted text as input to the program though. I would post things I have tried, but I have no idea where to start..

Comment: You could find any application that automatically copies the selected text into the clipboard. Then add some codes in your python application to get the data from the clipboard.